# H2 - READ_UNCOMMITED transaction doesn't read uncommited changes made by another transaction, why?

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, h2, isolation-level

READ_UNCOMMITED isolation level is supposed to have dirty reads, so in this scenario:

```
Thread1                              Thread2 (READ_UNCOMMITED)
  |                                     |
getAccount(1);                          |          
  |                                     |
updateAccount(account1)                 |                    
  |                                     |
 flush()                                |    
  |                                     |
  |                                   getAccount(1)
  |                                     |
 commitTx()                             |commitTx()
  |_                                    |_
```

`Thread2.getAccount(1)` should see the uncommited changes that are being made by Thread1, shouldn't it?

Well, I am no seeing that, the account I get with `baDao.findOne(accountId);` sees the original DB value, no the incremented one from the running Thread 1, what could be the explanation?

This is the place where **Thread1** updates the account:

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
@Override
public void addMoneyReadUncommited(int accountId, int ammount) {
    printIsolationLevel();
    BankAccount ba = baDao.findOne(accountId);
    ba.setMoney(ba.getMoney()+ammount);
    baDao.save(ba);
    flushEntityManager();
    logger.info("Money added");
}
```

I stop Thread1 at `logger.info("Money added");` and then **Thread2** runs:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true, isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
@Override
public BankAccount getReadUncommited(int accountId){
    printIsolationLevel();
    BankAccount account = baDao.findOne(accountId);
    logger.info("get({}) -> {}",accountId, account);
    return account;
}
```

Comment: If you are using v1.4 or higher of the H2 database and using the MVStore (which is the default), the default isolation level is `READ_COMMITTED` and setting the default isolation level on the data source or on the transaction [has no effect](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#transaction_isolation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the database I was using. I was testing with H2 and, for some unknown reason the second thread doesn't see the uncommited changes.

After changing to MariaDB everything behaves as expected